# Xcode: where is the option?

Tags: xcode, memory-leak

In [this instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html) Apple references "Instruments".

However, I don't see them in my Xcode install (version 5.1.1 for OSX 10.8).

Do I need to install something? Or its not available on that version?

Answer (score 1):

To run Instruments from Xcode:

1. Open Xcode.
2. Choose: Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments

[image]

Comment: yes, it did started, thx. However, step 3 talks about device and app selection. and I don't see those selections anywhere. Could you please make a screenshots of all those steps? Thank you in advance.